# c# asp.net master page get a href and set visible to false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an a href link in my user.master page, but I'm unable to find that control in my user.master.cs. How do I do so? I tried using master and find control, but it says object reference is not instance to an object or it does not work. Please help, thanks.

user.master

```
<a href="ViewPremiumPlans.aspx" id="showUpgradeLink" class="btn-light btn-sm">Upgrade</a>
```

user.master.cs
(first try)

```
var masterPage = Master;
 if (masterPage != null)
 {
     masterPage.FindControl("showUpgradeLink").Visible = true;
 }
```

(second try)

```
this.Master.FindControl("showUpgradeLink").Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you put **runat="server"** on the `a` tag?
For example:

```
<a href="ViewPremiumPlans.aspx" id="showUpgradeLink" runat="server" class="btn-light btn-sm" >Upgrade</a>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, without `runat="server"` it is just regular HTML, it needs that attribute to be a serverside control.

Comment: @Edgar Magallon i tried but it doesnt work as well

Comment: @anonymous `showUpgradeLink.visible = false` should now work. You don't need `FindControl()`. At what step in the page life cycle (on Load etc) are your calling this?

Comment: @JonP im putting this in pageload

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `runat="server"` without that it is not a server control.

```
<a href="ViewPremiumPlans.aspx" id="showUpgradeLink" runat="server" class="btn-light btn-sm">Upgrade</a>
```

You then access it in the master (user.master.cs) page directly

```
showUpgradeLink.visible = false;
```

If you want to expose it to child pages add a public property to user.master.cs

```
public HtmlGenericControl UpgradeLink { get { return showUpgradeLink; } };
```

In your child aspx pages where you want to access the control/property add:

```
<%@ MasterType  virtualpath="~/Path/To/user.master" %>
```

Then in the child .cs pages you can use:

```
Page.Master.UpgradeLink.visible = false;
```